# Sonata Admin edit form many to many not working - symfony2.1.6

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, sonata-admin

I am having a problem with implementing the many to many relationship in the sonata admin edit form, with the following structure.

```
purchase (id, total_price, discount, created_at)
purchase_product (purchase_id, product_id, quantity)
product (id, title, desc, price, thumbnail, created_at)
```

I have seen many threads and have tried the solutions listed in them. I have tried

```
->add('products', 'sonata_type_model', array('by_reference' => false))
```

I get the following error

```
No entity manager defined for class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
```

Then when i couldn't find a way to solve this, I switched to

```
->add('products', 'sonata_type_collection', array(), array('edit' => 'inline', 'inline' => 'table')
```

I got the following error

```
INVALID MODE type : sonata_type_collection - mapping : 8
```

I am also unable to figure out how to get and display the quantity from the purchase_product table.

Any pointers and help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

You can try to add 'expanded' => true and 'multiple' => true

```
->add('products', 'sonata_type_model', array('expanded' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'multiple' => true))
```

Comment: thanks Daniel, Is there a way i can load the last associated product  with the purchase along with its details, instead of loading all products with checkboxes - i also need to show the quantity which is in the purchase_product table (the linking table) - is there any way?